# Substitute for ClamXav

Tags: gratis, osx, antivirus

Now that [ClamXav has gone commercial](https://www.clamxav.com/changetocommercialsoftware), I would like to replace it with something else (I'm on a tight budget).

[ClamXav](https://www.clamxav.com) is a Mac OS X app for anti-virus detection and protection. Uses the [ClamAV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClamAV) engine.

Comment: Alex: It might be really helpful to expand your question to include what ClamXav does, which features you are looking for, etc., "I need SW to replace" or "Like" XXX tends to get voted down &/or for close.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com) makes a free version of their antivirus software for Mac.
You could also try Avast Free Mac Security and AVG AntiVirus for Mac.
You may need to register with these companies before you can download their software.

I have used Sophos but not the other two.